# How to choose between UC and PL when using the DPLL algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, logic, satisfiability, 3-sat, sat-solvers

We know DPLL algorithm is backtracking + unit propagation + pure
literal rule.

I have an example. There is one example to solve following Satisfiability problem with DPLL. if assign of "0" to variables is prior to assign "1" to variables, Which of Unit Clause (UC) or Pure Literal (PL) is used to solve this specific example?

> $\{\lnot A \lor B \lor C\}, \{A \lor \lnot B \lor C\}, \{A \lor B \lor \lnot C\}, \{A \lor B \lor C\}$

Olympiad Solution is: PL and UC.

Our Solution is just UC.

Who can satisfy me why Olympiad solution is correct ?!

Unit propagation is not possible as there are no unit clauses.

Pure literal rule is not applicable as there is no literals that occur
only positively or only negatively.

Update:
I think in node (3) we can user PL or UC. Isn't it?
[image]

Comment: Note that this question does not seem to have anything to do with AI; it's a pure logics question.

Comment: As far as I can see, you are correct.  Assigning variables as you described, *false* first then backtracking to *true* if a conflict occurs, you arrive at a solution using only unit propagation.  Pure literal elimination is never invoked.  This is the case regardless of the variable assignment order as the clause-variable graph is just one big automorphism.

Comment: @KyleJones Thanks, but I think there is a trick in this question.

Comment: @KyleJones please see my update.

Comment: The pure literal rule is applicable to (3), but it never would be applied because the unit rule is always applied first in DPLL.

Comment: Is there any source for your claims @KyleJones ?

Comment: @SaraPhD The original DPLL paper, "A Machine Program for Theorem Proving" describes the algorithm that way.  More practically, the pure literal rule is not applied in modern SAT solvers except for preprocessing.  It's too computationally expensive to be applied during the recursive search phase.  I've read of pure literal detection being worth the cost when attacking QBF formulas.

Comment: @KyleJones you are very expert but some problems, which page of your mentioned article say that unit rule is always applied first in DPLL?

Comment: it's also need to mentioned this is old Olympiad question not practical.

Comment: It's the first page of [the paper](http://www.ensiie.fr/~blazy/ipr/article2.pdf): "The algorithm of [1] used in testing for consistency proceeded by successive elimination of atomic formulas, first eliminating one-literal clauses (one-literal clause rule), and then atomic formulas all of whose occurrences were positive or all of whose occurrences were negative (affirma- tive-negative rule)."  Eliminating one-literal clauses is what you know as UC or the unit rule.  The affirmative-negative rule is known today as pure literal elimination or what you call PL.

Comment: @KyleJones please see page 12 on https://books.google.com/books?id=H5ZWLgcsc-8C&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=dpll+unit+clause+fail+pure+literal+solution&source=bl&ots=YtUAtArsmV&sig=rTwmxfeNvBVPSmrYmQL7ETCeskY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp9vDXlb_NAhUIYpoKHd3fBN0Q6AEIPzAF#v=onepage&q=dpll%20unit%20clause%20fail%20pure%20literal%20solution&f=false

Comment: @KyleJones would you please this book ans say your ideas?

Comment: If you switch the order of applying the unit rule and the pure literal rule then obviously the test question answer changes.  I think you should not be much concerned about the particulars of this apparently not so well-crafted question.  You seem to have a good grasp of the DPLL algorithm and that is the most important thing.

Comment: @KyleJones Please see this question as a very bad Olympiad question, can we say in general UC or PL can be used? would you please submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

If you use the original specification of the DPLL algorithm, in which the unit rule is applied to a fixed point and then the pure literal rule, then only the unit rule is needed to reach a satisfying assignment.  If the rule order is reversed then the pure literal rule is used to eliminate the final unsatisfied clause.

DPLL is a complete and sound algorithm for deciding Boolean satisfiability even if the pure literal rule is removed.  In practice, pure literals are typically removed only during the preprocessing of a SAT instance, where the formula is simplified as much as possible before beginning recursive search.  This is because detecting pure literals during search is computationally expensive enough to more than offset any expected runtime gains.